# Resizing Eventbrite ticket form iframe on a responsive template

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have embedded Eventbrite's ticket form code on my website successfully, however when it is viewed on mobile, the ticket form does not resize according with the responsive template. i am an amateur in this and have been trying all means to change the coding for the past few hours but to no avail.

Have seek help from Eventbrite but they are unable to give a solution. Is there anyone who can help to solve this problem?

Thank you so much in advance!

The code is as such:

```
<div style="width:100%; text-align:left;" ><iframe  src="www.example.com" frameborder="0" height="1000" width="100%" vspace="0" hspace="0" marginheight="5" marginwidth="5" scrolling="auto" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
<div style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial; font-size:10px; padding:5px 0 5px; margin:2px; width:100%; text-align:left;" ><a style="color:#ddd; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" href="http://www.eventbrite.sg/r/eweb">Sell Tickets</a> <span style="color:#ddd;">through</span> <a style="color:#ddd; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" href="http://www.eventbrite.sg?ref=eweb">Eventbrite</a></div>
</div>*
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to this. It actually depends on how you set up your event on eventbrite. There are some factors that will force your event to the full page view vs. the "Mobile Flow" view.

In my case I had to disable the "Group Registration" feature (Manage>Order From>Edit Group Registration>then click "Disable"). Note that if you just uncheck the ticket types it didn't work for me, because it said that at least one type needed to have group registration. So it is important to click the "Disable" button next to the save button.

The gentleman at eventbrite told me there are a few factors that will force full-site viewing, but if group registration isn't enabled on your event give them a call and they can tell you which feature to turn off.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add, that the "Mobile flow" vs. full page view will also affect your embed code. - the embed code I used was just the default one in eventbrite's management console.